# Unable to extend temp segment by 16 in tablespace PSTEMP

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft, ora-01652

The query that gives me this error was running for 6 months now and it was working fine. Today for some reason gave me this error:

> Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=1652, Message=ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 16 in tablespace PSTEMP (50,380).

I don't want to extend "PSTEMP" file. The query shouldn't be the problem as I mentioned it worked fine until now.

I don't know if that will help but the query has prompt value and if I enter a wrong value it works fine but when I enter the value from last week I know it should return 16 rows but instead I get the above error.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], and show a [mcve].

Comment: Running out of (temp) space does not necessarily mean there is something wrong with your query. But I can pretty much guarantee that the state of the database is different now compared to 6 months ago; more data (probably), different number of users, different usage pattern, etc. There is a good chance that just re-running the query again will work. Or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your temp space with

```
SELECT * FROM dba_temp_free_space;
```

but it might not necessarily be temp despite the error message.

Check your tablespace free space with:

```
select a.tablespace_name,sum(a.tots/1048576) Tot_Size,
     sum(a.sumb/1048576) Tot_Free,
     round(sum(a.sumb)*100/sum(a.tots),2) Pct_Free,
     sum(a.largest/1024) Max_Free,sum(a.chunks) Chunks_Free
     from
     (
     select tablespace_name,0 tots,sum(bytes) sumb,
     max(bytes) largest,count(*) chunks
     from dba_free_space a
     group by tablespace_name
     union
     select tablespace_name,sum(bytes) tots,0,0,0 from
      dba_data_files
     group by tablespace_name) a
     group by a.tablespace_name
order by pct_free;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your SQL became too heavy as the underlying data grew. You can try optimizing the SQL or if that's not an option, ask the DBAs to increase the undo tablespace (PSTEMP).